# dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):

Tags: ubuntu, apt, dpkg

`apt --fix-broken install` returns this:

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
python3-samba
The following packages will be upgraded:
python3-samba
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 60 not upgraded.
7 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,670 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up python3-minimal (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3-minimal
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

`sudo dpkg --configure -a` returns this:

Setting up python3-minimal (3.8.2-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python3-minimal.postinst: 5: py3compile: not found
dpkg: error processing package python3-minimal (--configure):
installed python3-minimal package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3-samba:
python3-samba depends on samba-libs (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1); however:
Version of samba-libs:amd64 on system is 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.2.
python3-samba depends on libwbclient0 (= 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.1); however:
Version of libwbclient0:amd64 on system is 2:4.13.17~dfsg-0ubuntu1.20.04.2.

dpkg: error processing package python3-samba (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba:
samba depends on python3-samba; however:
Package python3-samba is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of python3:
python3 depends on python3-minimal (= 3.8.2-0ubuntu2); however:
Package python3-minimal is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package python3 (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of netplan.io:
netplan.io depends on python3; however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package netplan.io (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of samba-common-bin:
samba-common-bin depends on python3; however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.
samba-common-bin depends on python3-samba; however:
Package python3-samba is not configured yet.
samba-common-bin depends on python3:any; however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package samba-common-bin (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent processing triggers for ufw:
ufw depends on python3:any; however:
Package python3 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package ufw (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving triggers unprocessed
Errors were encountered while processing:
python3-minimal
python3-samba
samba
python3
netplan.io
samba-common-bin
ufw

I tried to run these commands to fix the broken packages of python but they were all failing.
What else can I try to fix my problem?